# Remove percent-escaped characters from string

Tags: ios, swift

How do I *remove*, not decode, percent-escaped characters from a string using Swift. For instance:

`"hello%20there"`
should become
`"hellothere"`

EDIT:

I would like to replace multiple percent-escaped characters in a string. So:
`"hello%20there%0Dperson"`
should become
`"hellothereperson"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let string = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}", 
                                                 with: "",
                                                 options: .regularExpression, 
                                                 range: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method "removingPercentEncoding"

```
let precentEncodedString = "hello%20there%0Dperson"
let decodedString = precentEncodedString.removingPercentEncoding ?? ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for that matching `%` followed by two numbers: `%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`

```
let myString = "hello%20there%0D%24person"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}", options: [])
let range = NSMakeRange(0, myString.characters.count)
let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString,
                                                       options: [],
                                                       range: range,
                                                       withTemplate: "")
print(modString)
```

Comment: good call using a regex -- unfortunately, this doesn't _quite_ cover it, because there are hexadecimal characters sometimes following the `%`, not just 0-9.

Comment: @Gazzini Got it! It seems that the regex path was fixed by other answers but that's ok, I updated my regex to the correct value anyway :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
let input:String = "hello%20there%0Dperson"

 guard let output = input.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding else{
      NSLog("failed to remove percent encoding")
      return
  }

 NSLog(output)
```

and the result is

```
hello there
person
```

then you can just remove the spaces

or you can remove it by regex

```
"%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to _remove_, not decode, the special characters.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice in the first time I update my answer